# How to sync an Ubuntu machine inside AWS using NTP

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws, ntp

I have an Ubuntu instance inside AWS, which communicates with a third-party instance, also in AWS. I would like to ensure my instance's system time matches their's as close as possible.

They have told me their instance is synced using NTP.

I'm following this guide:

https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/use-timedatectl-and-timesyncd

and it says to use `systemctl status systemd-timesyncd`.

I get similar output to what they show.

Do I need to do anything more to be synched? Do I have to run this every so often?

I'm not sure if Ubuntu syncs via NTP by default and therefore I don't need to do anything.